# Sometimes Guest payment option not showing on IPhone even if I have enabled PayPal Account Option

Tags: ios, iphone, paypal, payment-gateway, paypal-sandbox

I am working on a project using a PayPal payment gateway. On this, I have enabled the 'guest checkout option' in my PayPal account(U.S Account) for customers paying on my website. Since some of our customers don’t have a PayPal account for payment(Payment such as Recurring or One time). When paying through PayPal.com using IPhone, it still asked to create an account. Sometimes it is showing the option to pay by credit card without logging in to PayPal. I want to show always the PayPal screens that appear to have the “Pay with Debit or Credit Card” option. How to achieve that? My IPhone screenshot is given below:

[image]

As per my research, I have found that we need to ‘ON’ the option ‘PayPal account optional’ in my PayPal Business account. I already changed it to ‘ON’. But still showing the same on my IPhone. Expected PayPal page is shown below:

[image]

Any help would be appreciable. Thank You!

Answer (score 1):

That option in the business account is a necessary, not a sufficient, condition for guest checkouts to be possible.

There is nothing that guarantees the availability of guest checkout. For every checkout attempt, PayPal makes its own case by case determinations about whether or not a guest checkout will be permitted, based on many factors.

An option you should consider is integrating a PayPal Checkout button that has a black 'Debit or Credit Card' button, as in the example here: https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/client

Comment: it is showing the option to pay by credit card without logging in to PayPal. But my IPhone not showing this option. Why does this happens? I want to show always the PayPal screens that appear to have the “Pay with Debit or Credit Card” option.

Comment: What you want is not possible. See the answer.